# Spring Cloud Contract can not produce json in producer side

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I want to write a contract using spring cloud contract in producer API.

My controller looks like :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/employee")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@RequestBody Request employeeRequest) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeRequest);
    if(employee.isPresent()){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).
                contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(employee.get());
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Request class :

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Request {
private Integer id;
 }
```

Response (Employee) class :

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
 public class Employee {

public Integer id;

public String fname;

public String lname;

public Double salary;

public String gender;

 }
```

Dsl written in groovy :

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

 Contract.make {
request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/employee'
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
    body(
            id : 25
    )

}
response {
    status 200
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
    body("""
{
    "id":25,
    "fname":"sara",
    "lname":"ahmadi",
    "salary":"25000.00",
    "gender":"F"
}
  """)

  }
}
```

Plugin in pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <baseClassForTests>example.co.ir.contractproducer.BaseTestClass</baseClassForTests>
                <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And BaseTestClass :

```
import io.restassured.config.EncoderConfig;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.config.RestAssuredMockMvcConfig;
import isc.co.ir.contractproducer.controller.EmployeeController;
import isc.co.ir.contractproducer.model.Employee;
import isc.co.ir.contractproducer.model.Request;
import isc.co.ir.contractproducer.service.EmployeeService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder;

import java.util.Optional;

@SpringBootTest
public class BaseTestClass {

@Autowired
private EmployeeController employeeController;

@MockBean
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@BeforeEach
public void setup(){

    Employee employee2=new Employee(25,"Adam","Brown",25000.0,"F");
    Request  request = new Request();
    request.setId(25);
    Mockito.when(employeeService.getEmployee(request)).thenReturn(Optional.of(employee2));

    EncoderConfig encoderConfig = new EncoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false);
    RestAssuredMockMvc.config = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig().encoderConfig(encoderConfig);

    StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder
            = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController);
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);

}
```

}

Generated test class:

```
import isc.co.ir.contractproducer.BaseTestClass;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import      io.restassured.module.mockmvc.specification.MockMvcRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions;

import static    org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.assertion.SpringCloudContractAssertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierUtil.*;
import static com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert.JsonAssertion.assertThatJson;
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public class ContractVerifierTest extends BaseTestClass {

@Test
public void validate_shouldReturnEmployee() throws Exception {
    // given:
        MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{\"id\":25}");

    // when:
        ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                .post("/employee");

    // then:
        assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
        assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");

    // and:
        DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['id']").isEqualTo(25);
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['fname']").isEqualTo("sara");
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['lname']").isEqualTo("ahmadi");
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['salary']").isEqualTo("25000.00");
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['gender']").isEqualTo("F");
}
```

}

Now when I build the project I get this error :

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.469      s <<< FAILURE! - in example.co.ir.contractproducer.ContractVerifierTest
[ERROR] validate_shouldReturnEmployee  Time elapsed: 0.607 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 

Expecting:
<500>
to be equal to:
<200>
but was not.
```

When I build project using Junit4 everything is work fine but while using Junit5 I had this problem.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you paste your base class and generated test together with all the imports?

Comment: I edit the question.@MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Can you print the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.139 s <<< FAILURE! - in .....contractproducer.ContractVerifierTest
[ERROR] validate_shouldReturnEmployee  Time elapsed: 1.217 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 

Expecting:
 <500>
to be equal to:
 <200>
but was not.
 at isc.co.ir.contractproducer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_shouldReturnEmployee(ContractVerifierTest.java:31) @MarcinGrzejszczak I can email you the whole project

Comment: No thank you. I see that you get 500 but have no idea why. Can you update the issue to have all the info?

Comment: Sure.When I build with junit4 everything is OK. and also here : employeeService.getEmployee(employeeRequest) in my controller class, if I change parameter to employeeRequest.getId and run test in junit5 it works. .So when I pass whole RequestBody to my service it dose not work. Thanks for your help. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Why do you start a springboottest when you're doing a standalone setup config of rest assured? Eitherdon't start the whole context and use standalone setup or start the context, autowire the webapplicationcontext and inject that into rest assured's webappcontext version of mockmvc (not the standalone one)

Comment: Do you mean remove SpringBootTest from my BaseTestClass,inject WebApplicationContext context and then RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context)?@MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Either renove SpringBootTest and use standalonesetup or leave springboottest and inject webappcontext

Comment: Thanks @MarcinGrzejszczak. This solution works fine.

Comment: Great! I've added an answer. Can we mark it as the proper one?

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `@SpringBootTest` and use `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup` or leave `@SpringBootTest`, inject `WebApplicationContext` and use `RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context)`